# Where is the SD card wear-leveling logic

Tags: linux, drivers, storage, sd-card

My understanding is that storage devices such as SD cards have wear-leveling logic to prolong the life-span of the card due to so many writes.

My confusion is , where is this logic or algorithm to control this? Is it on the card itself, or within the file-system driver (for Linux for example) of a computer that is writing to the card?

Answer (score 2):

There is potentially more than one level of wear-levelling involved (and potentially none):

- The flash controller on the SD card **may** have an implementation in its firmware. Not all do, especially early SD cards mostly did not: At this time the process was so much larger and the write speeds so much lower than today, that flash wear was not so much of an issue.
- The filesystem on the card may include it: Due to the first SD cards not having wear levelling quite an effort was made to introduce it on a higher layer. This proved to be quite a dead end, as the compatibility with different OSes suffered and it became nearly a Linux-only feature.

Even today you might encounter SD cards with no wear leveling at all - many cheap offers will simply accept, that a camera won't be able to write to the same card thousands of times.

Comment: Thanks. When you mention firmware on the SD card, do you mean, actual instructions that get executed? Do these instructions get executed by the host computer, or on the card itself. I have a hard time understanding this

Comment: @Engineer999 the host CPU just gives the card data and (logical) locations at which to write, the card has a microcontroller which then converts the location to a physical one, potentially rearranging the data to perform wear levelling, and writes the data. The CPU knows nothing about the physical flash arrangement.

Comment: The firmware is executed by the card's microcontroller: Only so can the same card work with different host hardware platforms.

Comment: Can you provide a reference that a Linux filesystem did wear-leveling for SD cards?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_file_system (or google for YAFFS)

Comment: @Mokubai Why does the host computer require specific file system drivers in that case? Shouldn't there be an abstraction as to how data is stored on the card? Thanks

Comment: @Engineer because the *filesystem* is how the operating system stores data on the card in a way that *it* understands. Below the filesystem is a block device, the SD card itself, and inside the SD card is another layer that takes that (logical) block device and maps it to physical flash blocks. The filesystem presents a simple view to applications and users. It's like an onion, lots of layers. Computers use lots of layers to simplify things for us meatsacks.

Comment: @EugenRieck -- The only interesting fs in the Wikipedia article is F2FS, but it doesn't seem to do wear-leveling.  The other flash-filesystems are intended for raw flash, not devices like SD cards and CompactFlash, which have a built-in flash translation layer (which present 512-byte blocks to the host).  When there's a FTL, wear-leveling by the fs simply is not feasible.  Turns out that you can run a fs such as JFFS2 on SD card using a shim layer such as mtd2block, but that might be to take advantage of the journaling capabilities rather than any (ineffective) wear-leveling.

Comment: @sawdust You need to read more carefully: Already the overview says, that "normal" file systems implement no wear leveling, but that log structured file systems (such as JFFS2 and YAFFS) include this property: The medium (e.g. flash) is written from start to end in erase-block sizes, which creates near-perfect wear-levelling at the cost of more random seeks, which are no problem with flash. In addition to that: It is 100% consistent with my experience.